# Joomla 2.5 after migrate issue

Tags: joomla, migration

I have migrated Joomla 1.5.26 site to Joomla 2.5 using upgrade.
After migration i got all my articles, menu and menu items.

But i am not able to see any article on site though they are assign to menu items in backed.

I compare all modules,categories and all to my 1.5 site and all data is as it is maintain in 2.5 migrated.

Still I am not able  to see my articles on site. Need help

Comment: i used jUpgrade to migrate.

Comment: It's really hard to know what's going on wihtout more inforation. What do you mean you don't see them? You click on the menu items and they don't display? or you can't type in a url for them? Something else?

Comment: I faced this problem, Saving again all menus and articles one by one worked for me. You can try this.

Comment: Try creating a new article, assign to a menu item. Can you see it now?

Comment: @tomjm No i even can't see newly added article on menu.

Comment: You cant see the menu item in front-end?

Comment: @tomjm I can see menu items in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try to go to menu management, select all menu items and then click **Rebuild** button on top.

If that doesn't help, you should check if your template is migrated properly.

Comment: Rebuil not worked for me. About template, i have converted 1.5 template to 2.5 supprtive by modifying XML file with reference link.

Comment: Might be issues with template too. Try to add these two lines at the top of your template's index.php file and see if you get any errors:  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');